# How get value of selected radio button in datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

***In below data list represents set of question's and answer, How to check whether the user selected right answer radio button or not when the user clicks on submit button using C#***

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        Q:
                        <asp:Label ID="QLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Q") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        A:<asp:RadioButton ID="rb1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("A") %>' GroupName="r"  />

                           <br />
                        B:
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rb2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("B") %>' GroupName="r"  />
                                           <br />
                        C:
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rb3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("C") %>' GroupName="r" />

                        <br />
                        D:
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rb4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("D") %>' GroupName="r"  />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=" Correct Anwser"></asp:Label>
                          </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>
                <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
                    DataFile="~/App_Data/Quize.mdb" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [Q], [A], [B], [C], [D] FROM [QuizData]">
                </asp:AccessDataSource>
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Summit" onclick="Button2_Click" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply reference to radioboxes rb1,rb2,rb3.... during submit i.e:

```
 if (rb1.Checked) {
      ///some code
   }
```

// EDIT

but if you cant, try to find reference to those radiobuttons and cast them as RadioButtons

```
RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton)dataItem.FindControl("rb1");
```